# Setting a default entry for the entry field

Tags: entry, field, channels, default

I have an entry field that is a selector tool for the page call to action at the bottom.

I have a channel of four or five entries and I'd like one of them to be the default selection so it's one less thing to setup on a site full of pages.

I haven't seen any details or questions for this sort of request as of yet so I thought I'd ask the question.

Thanks,
Jay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Entry fields do not natively support setting a default entry, but you can use the [**Globals**](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/globals.html) section to achieve the same effect.*

Create a 'Default Call to Action Entry' field in your globals, and set the default entry for all pages there. For extra functionality, I would then also have a 'Call to Action Entry' field on your entries.

With this set-up, a user can select a custom entry to use on that entry if they want, but by default it will fall-back to the entry selected in the Globals.

Your template would look something like this:

`{% set ctaEntry = entry.callToActionEntry.one|default('globalHandle.defaultCallToActionEntry.one') %}`

If you didn't want to build the ability to override the default entry on a per-page basis, you can just use the field in the Globals:

`{% set ctaEntry = globalHandle.defaultCallToActionEntry.one %}`

Comment: Beautiful idea, mate. I'll give that a go, cheers!

Comment: This worked a charm, by the way!

Comment: @Jay Glad to help :-)